# How to set TextArea height to its content height

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, flex4

I have an mx:TextArea and I want its height to be the same as its content height. There is nothing fancy - just a text area and text that is not editable. I need a simple and reliable way to make the control fit and show all the text without vertical scroll - something like auto resizing. Also my control's text will be set only once and will not change as it will not be editable.

```
<mx:TextArea id="myTextArea"
             editable="false"
             width="100%"
             verticalScrollPolicy="off" >
   <mx:text>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla id lorem 
      quis ante pulvinar auctor at eget risus. Nulla facilisi. Morbi ultricies 
      dignissim lorem, quis suscipit felis ullamcorper et.
   </mx:text>
</mx:TextArea>
```

There is one more post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731932/how-can-i-get-a-mxtextarea-height-to-be-the-same-as-the-content) on the same topic but it is not relevant to me because the setup there is a lot more complicated as it includes styling and binding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672402/spark-textarea-or-richtext-autosize

Answer (score 3):

Use the `textHeight` read-only property of the `TextArea`, and set the height of the TextArea to be TextArea.textHeight + whatever vertical padding the `TextArea` uses plus the height of the top and bottom borders (examine the `TextArea` component and figure those out). This process should happen in a handler you add to the `change` event for the `TextArea`.

Comment: note for others: `textHeight` property not available on spark components. Instead, just set TextArea property `heightInLines={NaN}` in mxml (or =NaN in AS3). See: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/01/18/creating-a-vertically-auto-resizing-spark-textarea-control-in-flex-4/

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code if you would like to stick with the spark text area component:

```
<s:TextArea 
   id="myTextArea"
   editable="false"
   width="100%"
   verticalScrollPolicy="off"
   change="myTextArea.height = myTextArea.scroller.viewport.contentHeight + 2;">
    <s:text>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla id lorem 
        quis ante pulvinar auctor at eget risus. Nulla facilisi. Morbi ultricies 
        dignissim lorem, quis suscipit felis ullamcorper et.
    </s:text>
</s:TextArea>
```

Or you can put the change handler in a function.

Comment: It doesn't work even in normal projects when text is set through code.
I suggest adapting height on `updateComplete` event.

Answer (score 0):

I've have great success with [Jack Moore's Autosize script](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/). It's lightweight and can be implemented on all your text areas with just one line: `autosize($('.MyTextAreaClass'));`

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest playing with "wordWrap='true'" in addition to the scroll policy.

Comment: No, that's not it. Word wrap will only transfer the text to a new line if it exceeds the width of the container.